# Obtain the probability generating function from a binomial looking function

Tags: probability, power-series, generating-functions, geometric-series

I am working through Stirzaker and Grimmett and found a problem and its solution that I was having difficulty understanding. It has been a while since I really played around with power series, so I might be missing some trick here.

The question is:

Find the generating function of the following mass function

$$
f(m) = \binom{n+m-1}{m}p^n(1-p)^m, \ \ \text{for} \ m \geq 0
$$

The solution, which is provided, is that the generating function $G(s)$ is:

$$
\Big\{\frac{p}{1 - s(1-p)}\Big\}^n
$$

I was not sure how the authors arrived at this solution. It looks like they use the normal trick for a geometric series where:

$$
\sum^\infty_{k=1}ar^k = \frac{a}{1-r}
$$

but I was not sure how they got the generating function above to fit into this form. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Differentiate $$\sum^\infty_{k=0}ar^k = \frac{a}{1-r}$$ on both sides with respect to $r$, $n-1$ times and see what you get. Notice the lower limit on that sum is $k=0$ btw.

Comment: Thanks @N.Shales I will give that a shot. I appreciate it.

Comment: If you manage to solve your problem then I suggest you post it as an answer here as I believe that is looked upon favorably by the MSE community.

Comment: The final formula in this table may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Tables_of_special_generating_functions

Comment: Have you learn about the negative binomial distribution and probability generating function? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution Essentially for a given pmf, it can be generated by the corresponding pgf. The pgf is given by $\displaystyle G(s) = E[s^X] = \sum s^x f_X(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n\geq 1$, note that
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}=(1-x)^{-n}
=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{-n}{m}(-1)^{m}x^{m}
=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+m-1}{m}x^{m}\quad (|x|<1)\tag{1}
$$
by the extended binomial theorem. In particular, it follows that
$$
\frac{p^n}{[1-s(1-p)]^n}==\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+m-1}{m}p^n(1-p)^{m}s^{m}
$$
by (1) which is the pgf of the negative binomial distribution as follows.